# Initialisation order in Lua Table Constructor

Tags: lua, lua-table

So, a table constructor has two components, list-like and record-like. Do list-like entries always take precedence over record-like ones? I mean, consider the following scenario:

```
a = {[1]=1, [2]=2, 3}
print(a[1]) -- 3
a = {1, [2]=2, [1]=3}
print(a[1]) -- 1
```

Is the index `1` always associated with the first list-like entry, `2` with the second, and so on? Or is there something else?

Comment: The result of `a = {1, [2]=2, [1]=3}` is not specified.  Real results will be different on PUC Lua and on LuaJIT.  Don't use such code in production.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Then so should be the result of  `a = {[1]=1, [2]=2, 3}` ?

Comment: [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior)

Answer (score -1):

There are two types of tables in Lua, **arrays** and **dictionaries**, these are what you call "lists" and "records". An *array*, contains values in an order, this gives you a few advantages, like faster iteration or inserting/removing values. *Dictionaries* work like a giant lookup table, it has no order, it's advantages are how you can use any value as a key, and you are not as restricted.

When you construct a table, you have 2 syntaxes, you can seperate the values with commas, e.g. `{2,4,6,8}` thereby creating an *array* with keys 1 through n, or you can define key-value pairs, e.g. `{[1]=2,[58]=4,[368]=6,[48983]=8}` creating a *dictionary*, you can often mix these syntaxes and you won't run into any problems, **but** this is not the case in *your* scenario.

What you are doing is defining the same key twice during the table's initial construction. This is most generally impractical and as such hasn't really had any serious thought put into it during the language's development. This means that what happens is essentially **unspecified behaviour**. It is not completely understood what effect this will have, and may be inconsistent across different platforms or implementations.

As such, you should not use this in any commercial projects, or any code you'll be sharing with other people. When in doubt, construct an empty table and define the key-value pairs afterward.

Comment: _"[…] hasn't really been thought about during the language's development"_ is incorrect. It has been considered, but the cost of checking for this (both time and code complexity) outweigh the benefits, so there is no check. Further (minor nit-pick), the behavior isn't _undefined_ but _unspecified_ (at least in the language used in the C and C++ standard) – it isn't the case that anything may happen, merely that the order of assignment for equal keys isn't defined.

Comment: @nobody Source that it's been considered? Also will edit in *unspecified*

Comment: Could not find the snippet that I was looking for but this exchange [1](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2007-03/msg00277.html), [2](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2007-03/msg00280.html) on the Lua-ML ~ten years ago shows that they were aware of that back then and had a working standalone static checker. Moving that logic into Lua is an obvious possibility (so I assume that option has been considered), yet Lua's behavior for duplicate keys hasn't changed across several new versions released since then.

Comment: Parts of this seem to be misleading for newbies. Arrays (correct Lua term is `sequence`) do not speedup iterations, as next() is hardly slower than function returned by ipairs(). Though some space *may* be saved, if table contains a sequence, i.e. non-nil values at integer keys in range 1..n for some positive n. And insert/remove into sequence is obviously O(n), while set into table key is O(1). These are simply not comparable. Also, accordingly to 5.3 manual, only the "order of assignment" is undefined for duplicate keys, not the "behavior".

Comment: @user3125367 Iterations are sped up because you can use a *numeric* for loop.